# Customize Activity Email

Tags: email, automation

I'm trying to customize my user's Activity Email.

[image]

Like for example, since I know which is the contact for this record I would like to have it autofilled, also for the subject.

Also, I would like to attach an attachment from my object automatically.

Is any of those wish actually implementable on SF? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try creating a new New action of Send email type and assigning it to your Quote object page layout.

Then you can predefine the values in your fields.